# Error Trying to get property 'num_rows'

Tags: php

Estou tentando logar, ao enviar os dados pro meu metodo, aparece esse error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in \controller\user.class.php on line 37
Notice: Trying to get property 'mysqli_num_rows' of non-object in \controller\user.class.php on line 38
```

```php
//LOGAR 
if (isset($_POST['btn-entrar'])) {
    $username = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['senha'];
    $password = md5($password);

    if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-info mb-2' role='alert'><strong>Atenção!</strong> Email ou Senha estão com os campos vazio, por favor, preencher.</div>";
    }else{
      $user = new User;

      if($user->getUser($username,$password)){
        session_start();
        //$_SESSION['logado'] = true;
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
        header("Location: ../index.php");
      }else{
        echo "<div class='alert alert-warning mb-2' role='alert'><strong>Atenção!</strong> Esse usuario não existe.
                </div>";
      }
    }
}
```

```php
//CLASSE
<?php 
//includes
//include_once '../model/connection.php';
class Database{
    private $servername;
        private $user;
        private $password;
        private $dbname;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->servername = 'localhost';
            $this->user = 'root';
            $this->password = '';
            $this->dbname = '';
        }

        public function connect(){
            $conn = new mysqli($this->servername,$this->user,$this->password,$this->dbname);
            return $conn;
        }
}

    class User extends Database{

        public function getUser($username,$senha){
            $obj = new conectar();
            $conexao = $obj->conexao();

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$username' AND senha = '$senha'";




        $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
        //print_r($result);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)== 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
    }
```

**ONDE EU ESTOU ERRANDO?**

Comment: Você fez: `$result->num_rows`. Você verificou qual é o valor de `$result`? Isto é, leu a documentação do método `query` quanto ao retorno?

Comment: opa , na verdade o if era a variavel, porem tava fazendo alguns teste e copiei e coloquei desse jeito, mas vamos la, 
verifiquei o valor do $result,

Comment: fiz algumas mudanças ai,

Comment: aparece seguinte error, apos algumas devidas mudanças
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Comment: E o que mudou com essas mudanças? Qual o novo erro? Qual o novo resultado?

Comment: se você está usando aspas duplas não precisa concatenar as variaveis com aspas simples, as variaveis em php são lidas dentro de aspas duplas, só um comentario msm

Comment: Se você realmente leu a documentação, viu que a função, em casos específicos, retorna `true` ou `false`. Você não validou isso no código e o erro está te dizendo exatamente isso: **bool given**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o problema pode ser esse trecho

```
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
if ($result->mysqli_num_rows== 1) {
    return true;
}
```

Segundo a documentação o `msqli::query` pode retornar `false` ou [`MySQLi_Result`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php), ou seja a primeira coisa que você deve fazer e verificar se a variavel `$result` não é `false`, e ainda segundo a documentação o `MySQLi_Result` **não tem uma propriedade** com o nome de `mysqli_num_rows` **e sim um método com esse nome**, então deve ser chamado da seguinte forma `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Aplicando a correção seu código ficaria +/- assim:

```
if( $result ){
    // $result e um objeto 'MySQLi_Result'

    if ($result->mysqli_num_rows()== 1) {  // faltava o () `parenteses`
        return true;
    }

    /// nao entrou no if

}
return false;
```

---

> #### [`mysqli::query`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues)
>
> **Valor Retornado**
>
> ---
>
> Returns **`FALSE`** on failure. For successful *`SELECT`*, *`SHOW`*, *`DESCRIBE`* or *`EXPLAIN`* queries `mysqli_query()` will return a **`mysqli_result`** object.
>    For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return **`TRUE`**.
>
> **Que traduzido ficaria +/- assim:**
>
> Retorna **`FALSE`** quando falha.
>   No sucesso de queries do tipo *`SELECT`*, *`SHOW`*, *`DESCRIBE`* ou *`EXPLAIN`* retorna um objeto **`mysqli_result`**.
>   No sucesso de outros tipos queries retorna **`TRUE`**

[A classe MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli.php)

Comment: entao, eu fiz essa alguns alterações, no texto,
estou reelendo a a documentação do msqli::query, pra ver. pq apresentou um novo erro, 

 MySQLi_Result nao tem uma variavel mysqli_num_rows(EXATAMENTE) ai foi alguns testes loucos que estava fazendo, achando q errei algo, em poo
 $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
   

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result)== 1) {
    return true;
   }
   return false;

Comment: Muito obrigado, ensinou muito e ajudou muito, obrigado mesmo, se eu pudesse dava 10 logo, valeu.